# How to avoid the weird effect when changing tabs?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I'm embedding a flash inside an html, the app is made using Starling, and when I switch tabs in the browser (checked it in IE and Chrome) the frame that belongs to the game, is filled with what was before in the previous tab, for ~1 second, then it switches to the actual content.

This effect is undesirable, and I was wondering, is this Stage3D fault?, Starling fault?, my fault?.

I tested other games, like the ones that are hosted in Kongregate, and this effect doesn't happen, which makes me believe that it is the way the flash is embedded, or that those games are not using Stage3D to render, or, are embedded using another technique.

Screenshot added to illustrate the problem better, as you can see, the Flash container is filled with the previous tab visual content.

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's beyond your control (and is likely to be OS/Browser/Display specific). However, I just did a test embed and I did not get this when swapping tabs. Is your embed online somewhere to compare to?

Comment: test on different computers/browsers to get a good picture of what's going on.

Comment: I tested on 3 different computers, the same happens. Then I tested games on Kongregate, that have several flash tittles there, and it didn't happen.. which makes me think there is a way to avoid the weird effect.

Comment: likely it's what you suggest, or starling and the way it handles lost focus. Have you tested other starling games?

Comment: No, only one. I will test other games, but I don't think that will provide me with a solution.

Comment: can you add a screenshot maybe? this problem sounds very interesting, thx!

Comment: Sure, screenshot added to show what is happening more visually.

Comment: It's more of a browser fault, than either Starling or Flash fault. But, to eliminate either Starling or Flash, check repeatedly what's the `stage.frameRate` from within your SWF, probably display it right there as a historic graph (like perfmon), swap, wait then swap back and check if frame rate dropped to say 0.5 or less. If this is true, you might want to set frame rate on focus lost event, or tweak Starling framework into doing the same.

Comment: And yes, if you're seeing Kongregate kids to overcome this somehow, you might ask there as well, probably some of their residents will be willing to help on topic.

Comment: Yeah, I've just asked there too. I've placed a native display list rectangle to cover the entire stage, just to check if it was something Starling/Stage3D related, and the same glitch happens.